# There's so much space between votes!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, voting

Likely a result of the new CSS updates applied earlier, the spacing when clicking to determine the vote splits on posts is... way more spacious than usual. Look at it!

[image] That's just a normal view!

[image] Super spacious splits!

Comparison with past design:

> [image]        [image]

The gap increased from 15px to 20px.

Comment: So… what is this about?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 It's just a bug report. Basically, I want it to go back to the way it was :)

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.

Comment: Doubt it's a bug, i.e. that's likely the intended behavior. @Adam can confirm though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No idea. I'm just here to edit [design] tag into design bugs. ;)

Comment: As far as I know, nothing has been changed concerning the voting button padding. I'll double-check tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure they've always been this spacious.

Comment: @Hynes fact is, it changed, from 15px to 20px, see edit. Maybe undesired effect of some other change

Comment: @Hynes digging a bit, I noticed the line-height of the body has been changed from 1.3em to just 1.3 - wasn't this intended?

Comment: @Hynes it definitely changed; I saw it, wondered what was going on, and found my way to this question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Changing the line-height from 1.3em to 1.3 was intended as we're trying to make line-height unitless and more versatile. I see that this had too many little effects. I've rolled back the line-height to 1.3em for now until we can address these other issues.

Comment: Thanks @Hynes - and that's probably worth an answer and [tag:status-completed], no? :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here seems to stem from changing the line-height from `1.3em` to `1.3` as **Shadow Wizard** [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270468/theres-so-much-space-between-votes#comment876474_270468). Changing the line-height was intended as we're trying to make line-height unitless. However since seem this had too many little effects, I've restored the line-height to its previous value until we can address these other issues.